# SELECT all elements that don't exist in another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables, a USER table which contains all current users. The next table is called tasks and has a lot of information, one of the columns is PointPerson which is the same as one of the columns in the user table. This column has entries for people who are not users anymore. This is what I want to get from a SELECT statement. I want all of the users in the task table that don't exist on the user table.

This is what I have tried but I am getting no responses which can't eb correct:

```
SELECT DISTINCT TSK.PointPerson FROM [Task] AS TSK
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
SELECT DisplayName FROM [User]
)
```

What am I doing wrong and how do I get the desired result?

Comment: To answer half of your question: You have a `WHERE NOT EXISTS` clause that is not correlated with your `SELECT` query. If there are _any_ rows in `User` then it will cause no rows to be returned from `Task`. The reverse is also true: if there are no rows in `User` then you will get back all rows from `Task`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT TSK.PointPerson FROM [Task] AS TSK
WHERE TSK.PointPerson NOT IN (
SELECT DisplayName FROM [User]
)
```

Or a different approach:

```
SELECT DISTINCT TSK.PointPerson FROM [Task] AS TSK
LEFT JOIN [User] AS U ON U.DisplayName = TSK.PointPerson 
WHERE U.DisplayName IS NULL
```

Answer (score 2):

You may try like this:-

```
SELECT DISTINCT TSK.PointPerson
FROM [Task]
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
    (SELECT DisplayName  
     FROM User
     WHERE Task.name = User.name)
```

or using a LEFT JOIN like this:-

```
SELECT DISTINCT TSK.PointPerson
FROM Task t1
LEFT JOIN User t2 ON t2.name = t1.name
WHERE t2.name IS NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do this

```
SELECT PointPerson 
FROM [Task]
EXCEPT
SELECT DisplayName 
FROM [User]
```